# NoClassDefFoundError for tomcat servlets

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have a Java EE Web project deployed and running fine (project1)..

I create another project (project2) and add project1 in Web Deployment Assembly..

I am able to access all classes defined in project1 and no compile time error..

While running the project, it gives runtime error like NoClassDefFoundError for classes in project1..

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Is it even possible? One .war file containing another .war file under libs... Will it reference it correctly? Because it's not doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the project1 is absent from project2 classpath. Try to compile project1 to a jar (I assume it's a .war now) and put the jar on the classpath.

`War` files are not library files as `jars` are. They have the specific purpose of packaging a webapp in one distributable file. Your IDE is apparently smart enough to reach into the war, but that's not a rule.

IMO the best you can do is to create another project where you put all the shared classes and package it as a jar (say, `project3.jar`). Then, put `project3` as a dependency of both `project1` and `project2` and you'll have a clean, legible structure that works.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by updating classpath.. I have put project1 in Web Deployment Assembly with the path "WEB-INF/lib/project1.war"..

Comment: OK some progress.. It can refer to shared classes in project3.. But jars which are included in project3 are not available?

Comment: Correct - all the transitive dependencies need to be handled as well. In your case manually, which will drive you crazy at some point. Before that, take a look at maven or gradle. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-transitive-dependency-to-my-projects-classpath.html  https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html

Comment: For now copying all jars from all dependent project in WEB_INF/libs dir.. Eclipse must include them automatically..